# BluetoothLE service discovery error on Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, service-discovery

I'm currently working on an application for connecting to a special board whose software is developed by another company using both classic Bluetooth and Bluetooth LE (of course not at the same time). The used Panasonic PAN1026 allows a reliable classic Bluetooth SPP connection.

The issue is that altough the connection to the GATT server can be established successfully, I am unable of performing a service discovery when using Bluetooth LE. The service discovery does not return any results even after ten minutes, as shown by the log below:

```
02-04 20:06:39.137  31757-31757/... D/BluetoothGatt﹕ connect() - device:     26:0B:D9:55:55:55, auto: false
02-04 20:06:39.137  31757-31757/... D/BluetoothGatt﹕ registerApp()
02-04 20:06:39.137  31757-31757/... D/BluetoothGatt﹕ registerApp() - UUID=e4b1b4b7-52d6-433a-9071-88fd5d6bf556
02-04 20:06:39.137  31757-31757/... I/BluetoothGatt﹕ Client registered, waiting for callback
02-04 20:06:39.137  31757-31769/... D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
02-04 20:06:40.047  31757-31768/... D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=5 device=26:0B:D9:55:55:55
02-04 20:06:40.047  31757-31768/... I/bluetoothle.GATTHandler﹕ Bluetooth LE connection established!
02-04 20:06:40.047  31757-31768/... D/BluetoothGatt﹕ discoverServices() - device: 26:0B:D9:55:55:55
02-04 20:06:40.047  31757-31768/... I/bluetoothle.BluetoothLEConnection﹕ Starting service discovery: true
```

Here's my code:

```
    this.gattHandler = new GATTHandler(this);
    // run the service discovery on the UI thread for being compatible with Samsung mobile phones
    if (this.getDisplayFragment().getActivity() != null)
    {
        this.getDisplayFragment().getActivity().runOnUiThread(
        new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                gattConnection = getDeviceToConnectTo().connectGatt(getDisplayFragment().getActivity().getApplicationContext(), false, gattHandler);
            }
        });
    }

public class GATTHandler extends BluetoothGattCallback
{
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState)
    {
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED)
        {
            this.setGATTConnectionState(GATTHandler.STATE_CONNECTED);
            this.getEventNotifier().onConnectionEstablished();
            Log.i(GATTHandler.TAG, "Bluetooth LE connection established!");
        }
        else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED)
        {
            this.setGATTConnectionState(GATTHandler.STATE_DISCONNECTED);
            this.getEventNotifier().onDisconnected();
            Log.i(GATTHandler.TAG, "Bluetooth LE connection closed!");
        }
        else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING)
        {
            this.setGATTConnectionState(GATTHandler.STATE_CONNECTING);
            Log.i(GATTHandler.TAG, "Establishing a Bluetooth LE connection!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status)
    {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS)
        {
            Log.i(GATTHandler.TAG, "Discovered some services!");
            this.getEventNotifier().onServicesDiscovered();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.wtf(GATTHandler.TAG, "Service discovery status: " + String.valueOf(status));
        }
    }
}
```

However, when using gattool on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 the service discovery works, as shown by the output below:

```
hcitool lescan
26:0B:D9:55:55:55 Spp

gatttool -I -b 26:0B:D9:55:55:55
[   ][26:0B:D9:55:55:55][LE]> connect
[CON][26:0B:D9:55:55:55][LE]> primary
[CON][26:0B:D9:55:55:55][LE]> 
attr handle: 0x0001, end grp handle: 0x0021 uuid: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0100, end grp handle: 0x0131 uuid: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0200, end grp handle: 0x0212 uuid: e079c6a0-aa8b-11e3-a903-0002a5d5c51b
[CON][26:0B:D9:55:55:55][LE]> disconnect
[   ][26:0B:D9:55:55:55][LE]>
```

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo with the original Android 4.4.2 ROM for developing. I have already read the following two questions and thus I think Android's BlueDroid is a bit buggy:

[Question A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864263/nexus-5-bluetoothle-service-discovery-unreliable)
[Question B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070562/bluetooth-low-energy-service-discovery-with-android-4-3-on-nexus-4)

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Lukas

Comment: On a G3, you may have to use Samsung's BLE API. http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=GeneralB&messageId=157757

Comment: According to Samsung, their API is deprecated starting with Android 4.3: http://developer.samsung.com/ble (before download section)

Comment: Gotcha... I had given up on S3 Samsung and BLE a while back, specifically for their horrible developer support.

Comment: Okay, that doesn't sound good. I don't have any other BLE capable Android phone available. Sounds like I have to buy another phone and sell my Samsung. Do you want to buy it (free leather case included) ;)

Comment: Ha... no, thanks. I got an unused Nexus 5 in the box, and a gently used Nexus 4... ;) Try the nRF tools tho, before you give up. If those work, I have a spare (legal) access code to the nRF sources.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp

Comment: Yes. Samsung BLE SDK was a temporary solution since Android was very late to introduce a BLE API. It does not support any service discovery functionalities though.

Comment: @323go I've tried the nRF tools, but these tools are also unable to discover the services running on the board. Even directly accessing a service via the UUID does not work. I'll inform the company developing the board and the software about it. Our project management teacher was right, working with external companies is not that easy.